# couldn't get through admin and user login at the same time in laravel

Tags: laravel

I am trying to create an e-commerce site, where I have admin and user panel. If admin and user login Separate there is no conflict but at if logged in at the same time there is a problem. Suppose I logged in as a user , there is no problem with user section and I can access all of the properties in user section but it also allows me to visit admin section but I ain't interested to do that. Moreover, it displays the currently logged user's name in admin section.I used Auth::user()->name  in admin and user section to display the name. The above problem is occurred vice versa.

AdminController

```
public function login(Request $request)
{
    if($request->isMethod('post'))
    {
        $data = $request->input();

        if(Auth::attempt(['email'=>$data['email'], 'password'=>$data['password'],      'role'=>'admin']))
        {
    
            Session::put('adminaccount', $data['email']);
            return redirect('/admin/index');
        }
        else{
          
            return redirect('/admin')->with('failed_message', 'Invalid Credentials');
        }
    }

    return view('admin.login'); 
}

public function logout()
{
    // auth()->logout(); two method for logout
    Session::flush();

    Session::forget('adminaccount'); 

    return redirect('/admin')->with('success_message', 'Logout successfully.');
}
```

UserController

```
 public function login(Request $request)
{
    $this->validate($request, [

        'emaillogin' => ['required', 'email'],

        'passwordlogin' => ['required']
    ]);

    if(Auth::attempt(['email' => $request->emaillogin, 'password' => $request->passwordlogin, 'role' => 'user'])){

        Session::put('useraccount', $request->emaillogin); //from useraccountmiddleware

        return redirect('/cart');
    }
    else{

        return redirect()->back()->with('invalid', 'Invalid Credentials!');
    }
}

 public function logout()
{
    Auth::logout();

    Session::forget('useraccount');  

    Session::forget('session_id');

    return redirect('/');
}
```

Comment: you need to make middleware of it to check if the following routes is accessible by specific role user

Comment: why the 2 seperate logins when there is only a 'User'? regardless of role

Comment: As Zero said, you need to add a column to your User table to allow an array of Roles to be stored. Then create a middleware on /admin/ routes to specify a user must have the "admin" role to access. There are plenty of guides on this, but honestly it's a simple concept and you will likely be better just doing it yourself - you will learn things that you wouldn't from copy/pasting.

Comment: actually I created two middleware for admin and user also use the following lines of code to prevent                                                                                                     Route::group(['middleware' => ['adminaccount']], function (){  //other routes } this is for admin .                                                                    Route::group(['middleware' => ['useraccount']], function (){  //other routes } for user